# Regex of binary strings that have at least one 1 and an even number of 0

Tags: regex

I want to find a regex binary string expression that has at least one 1 and an even number of 0.

For strings that has an even number of 0, I have:

```
1*(01*01*)*
```

For strings with at least one 1, I have:

```
0*1(0+1)*
```

However, I struggle to combine the two together. Can anyone give me a hint on how to do it? thanks!

Comment: What type/implementation of regex is this question about?

Comment: Sorry it's a theoretical CS question. So not Linux-regex style

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without any fancy regex stuff, just `^` start, `$` end [anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) and [`|` pipe](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), how about

```
^(00)*(1|01+0)(1*01*0)*1*$
```

Should be self explanatory. [Play with it at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3IASsA/4). Hope I've not overlooked anything :)

If [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) are allowed, I could also think of a negative one: [`^(?!0*$)(?:1*01*0)*1*$`](https://regex101.com/r/BCG7jM/1)

Comment: That is pretty nifty ++ So this would match the even zeroes on the left hand side, match a 1 or 010 as the minimum required 1 and matches the even 00 on the right hand side right?

Comment: Thanks @Thefourthbird fun playing with :) Yes, the challenge was the first part `^(00)*(1|01+0)` until the required `1` I hope it's working as desired.

Comment: There was an error, didn't work on eg `01101`. Let me know if more errors :p

Answer (score 1):

One option to match an even number of zeroes and at least a single 1 might be using a positive lookahead `(?=` (if supported)

```
^(?=(?:1*01*01*)+$)0*1[10]*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

  - `(?:1*01*01*)+$` Repeat 1+ times matching two times a zero with optional one's
- `)` Close lookahead
- `0*1` Match zere or more times a zero, then match the required one
- `[10]*` Match 0+ times a zero or one
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/azKyc6/1)

---

To also match only one's (so without a zero) you could use

```
^(?=(?:(?:1*01*01*)+|1+)$)0*1[10]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/20OYPs/1)

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with Linux-regex style. Do you know how to convert into theoretical CS style using only *, + (for union), empty string, and brackets? Thank you!

Comment: @javita This pattern is supported by engines that support a positive lookahead `(?=`

Comment: Will it be correct if I write (1*01*01*)(1*01*01*)* 0*1(0+1)* ? I'm not sure what $)0*1[10]*$ does, since you have two $, which means that the 0*1[10]* part is optional?

Comment: it's definitely not the same. Look at @Thefourthbird's regexp which says that there *might* be a bracket `(?`, but yours says that there must be one bracket at the begin of an expression

Comment: @javita This part `(?=(?:1*01*01*)+$)` is an assertion (non consuming) which makes sure that what is on the right are pairs of 2 times a zero to adhere to the even requirement. This part `0*1[10]*$` makes sure that there is at least a single 1.

Comment: Seems it doesn't match `1` (0 is even).

Comment: @aventurin Ah I see, I only considered that there should at least be 2 times a zero. I have added an update to the answer with a modified pattern.

Comment: @bobblebubble Nice one, you should add it to your answer as well!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your requirements correctly, but if `+` should stand for alternation (normally `|`), and only `*`, `+`, and brackets are allowed (as your comment below suggests) then

`(1*01*01*)*(11*+011*0)(1*01*01*)*`

should work.

The idea is that there must exist a `1` such that either left and right from it must be an equal number of `0`s or left and right from it must be an odd number of `0`s: `(11*+011*0)`

Your `0*1(0+1)*` would also match `01` so I believe it doesn't work.

In either case left and right from such a group there can exist an equal number of `0`s with an arbitrary number `1`s in between: `(1*01*01*)*`.

In most regex implementations the above regex would be written as

`^(1*01*01*)*(11*|011*0)(1*01*01*)*$`.

Comment: Interesting answer! Unfortunately have daily vote limit reached and can't upvote right now (4 hours). I don't think, the `|` should be replaced by `+` but I wonder if there would be a regex that works without `|`. Your explanation of `0*1(0+1)` is on point :) Further I think you could even replace `11*` with `1+`

Comment: Yes, you're right, `11*` could be replaced with `1+` using the common syntax. I wrote it that way because it seemed to me that @yavita had another "CS style" syntax in mind.